# Howto getCenter in gmap from list of markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs

How do I use the getCenter() function with a list of picked markers from my gmap(3.0)?

Right now im trying this approach

```
Ext.each(myRecords, function (r) {
if (...) {
myArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(r.get('Latitude'), r.get('Longitude')));
}
});
```

Is there a easy way to get the furthest markers from that array? If i can get that i might be able to do:

```
var myLatLng = ...   
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
bounds.getCenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are actually asking for. But to answer the question as you have proposed it in the title:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
Ext.each(myMarkers, function (m) {
    bounds.extend(m.getPosition());
});
bounds.getCenter();
```